# Evaluate $\int_\gamma (z^2+\pi^2)^{-1}dz$ using Cauchy Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $\gamma: [0,4\pi] \to \mathbb{C}$ be given by

$$\gamma: \gamma(t)=\begin{cases} 
3te^{it}, & \text{if $0\le t \le 2\pi$} \\[2ex]
10\pi -2t, & \text{if $2\pi \le t \le 4\pi$.} 
\end{cases}
$$

Evaluate the integral $\int_\gamma (z^2+\pi^2)^{-1}dz$.

The hint of this exercises says Use the Cauchy theorem for multiply connected domains and the Cauchy Integral Formula. However, the curve $\gamma$ is not even closed here, so how can we apply the Cauchy theorem?
 I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: If you close the curve in the obvious way what answer will Cauchy's theorem give? This gives another way of computing the above.

Comment: @copper.hat I get $0$ by taking the integral over the enclosed curve. Then do we subtract the integral over the extended line?

Comment: No. You just need to evaluate the integral from $2\pi$ to $0$ and negate the result.

Comment: @copper.hat Just to be clear. So you mean negate $\int_{2\pi}^0 (t^2+\pi^2)^{-1}dt$ right?

Comment: Well, you understand what is happening, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Cauchy's theorem (as opposed to the residue theorem) you need a little care. Let $\eta$ be the curve joining
$\gamma(4\pi)$ to $\gamma(0)$. Call the curve $\gamma$ followed
by $\eta$ to be $\gamma+\eta$.

First you must show that $\int_{\gamma+\eta} f(z)dz = 0$ from which
it follows that
$\int_\eta f(z)dz = -\int_\gamma f(z)dz$